# How to vertically align shape text in Gliffy?

Tags: gliffy

In [Gliffy](http://www.gliffy.com/), I have a rectangle shape and I want to draw another rectangle inside it. I need a name for both of the rectangles. I can give shape a name by selecting the shape and starting to type.

My problem is, I can't find a reasonable way to align the text vertically, only horizontally. I can just hit enough line breaks after the text to move the text upper, but in my opinion this is a hack solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way to do it is to dissociate the text from the box and thus make them two different objects. This way, you can manipulate their alignment both on horizontal as well as on vertical.

Comment: This is something I've already used (though forgot to mention in the question). It just makes the process quite a bit clumsy :(